# Will we get troll bots?

Tags: discussion

I was reading [this](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/oct/14/russia-us-politics-social-media-facebook) article, and it occurred to me, given that philosophy.stackexchange is such a hotbed of international mystery and so forth, will it begin to attract political opponents?

I mean this at face value, not suggesting anyone in particular is (or will be!).

Comment: given what just happened to my pc, i'm guess 'yes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear we may already have them

Comment: i suspect you're right tbh